# GridView try to render first item TOO MANY TIMES

Tags: android, android-gridview, baseadapter

I have this code in the getView method in my custom BaseAdapter:

```
public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.e("blah","getView "+position);
    View itemView = convertView;
    ItemController renderer;
    ItemType item = getItem(position);
    if (itemView == null) {
        renderer = createNewRenderer(item);
        renderer._setItem(item);
        itemView = renderer.createLayout(inflater);
        renderer.init();
    } else {
        renderer = (ItemController) itemView.getTag();
        if (renderer.getItem() != null && renderer.getItem() != item) {
            renderer.dispose();  // Recycle images and other stuff
            dispose(renderer);   // I need to keep a mapping between the items in the gridview to the renderers, this will point older item to nothing.
        }
//          if (!reuseViews)
//              itemView = renderer.createLayout(inflater);
        renderer._setItem(item);
    }

    populateController(item, renderer);
    renderer.renderImpl();
    return itemView;
}
```

And this is the output of rendering a 3x3 GridView:

```
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #1
getView #2
getView #3
getView #4
getView #5
getView #6
getView #7
getView #8
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
```

I render the content of each of the ItemRenderer dynamically after it is loaded...

NOTE how nicely all the items behaves except the first item.

And when I scroll down:

```
getView #9
getView #10
getView #11
getView #12
getView #13
getView #14
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #15
getView #16
getView #17
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #18
getView #19
getView #20
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #21
getView #22
getView #23
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #24
getView #25
getView #26
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #27
getView #28
getView #29
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
getView #0
```

Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: I've also tried to create a new view for every call... didn't change the result.

Comment: this log does not exactly match your code, there is a `#`. Are you sure the #0 log comes from the adapter?

Comment: Make sure you are not calling notifyDataSetChanged() too many times. You must know, howhever, that the developer has no control over the way that `getView()` method is called.

Comment: Good points but these are not the cases. notifyDataSetChanged is only called once... otherwise the other items would also be rendered. About the log, I've typed that line here instead of pasting it from the code, its a typo. Thanks.

Comment: I know that the system manages the getview calls... but this is ridiculesly too much. I probably do something wrong and just can't put my finger on it.  Any other thoughts?